# how can i display sub menu horizantal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created one responsive navigation menu with sub menu. Sub menu display list item in vertically. I want to display sub menu item into horizontally.

I refereed this below link but this is also not working into my style sheet :-

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_float

CSS :-

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700);
#cssmenu {
    background: #4cb6ea;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
#cssmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul:after,
#cssmenu:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease;
    transition: color .2s ease;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li {
     max-height: 0;
     position: absolute;
     -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
     -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
     -o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
     transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
     background: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 13px;
    right: 15px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 15px;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
    right: auto;
    left: 15px;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: #ffffff;
}


#cssmenu ul li ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #000000;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 170px;
    padding: 11px 10px 11px 20px;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul li ul li.active > a {
    color: #4cb6ea;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover:after,
#cssmenu ul li ul li.active:after {
    background: #4cb6ea;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul > li {
    max-height: 72px;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
    text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
    float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
    right: 100%;
    left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
    text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: height .2s;
    -moz-transition: height .2s;
    -ms-transition: height .2s;
    -o-transition: height .2s;
    transition: height .2s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
    padding-right: 40px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 13px;
    right: 14px;
    top: 16px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #4cb6ea;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 21px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active:after {
    height: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
    color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after {
    background: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:before,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:before {
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
    max-height: 72px;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    width: auto;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #cssmenu > ul {
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
        -ms-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
        -o-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
        transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right ul li a {
        text-align: left;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
        text-align: left;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li > a {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
        text-align: left;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
        display: block;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul.open {
        max-height: 1000px;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.25);
    }
    #cssmenu ul {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu ul > li {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
    }
    #cssmenu ul > li:after {
        display: none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after,
    #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:before,
    #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after,
    #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
        display: none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul,
    #cssmenu ul li ul li ul,
    #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul,
    #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul,
    #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li ul,
    #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li:hover > ul {
        left: 0;
        position: relative;
        right: auto;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul li,
    #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
        max-height: 999px;
        position: relative;
        background: none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul li a {
        padding: 8px 20px 8px 35px;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul ul li a {
        padding: 8px 20px 8px 50px;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a {
        color: #000000;
    }
    #cssmenu #menu-button {
        display: block;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: #ffffff;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        height: 3px;
        width: 22px;
        border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
        right: 20px;
        top: 16px;
    }
    #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        height: 3px;
        width: 22px;
        border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
        right: 20px;
        top: 26px;
    }
}
```

HTML Code :-

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on in that CSS file but it looks like you're missing a `float: left` when defining `ul li ul li`.

I believe you'll add it here:

```css
#cssmenu ul li ul li {
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  float: left; /* this is where you'll add it. */
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Hey I am try this but sub menu not display horizontal